# SQL to find the average amount of money spent by country?

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I need to find the average amount of money spent by country, using the two tables below in oracle.  Sale_total is the money spent in each sale and Cust_country is the customer's country.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tables

**Sale**

```
Sale_Id
Payment_ID
Ship_Id
Customer_ID
Sale_total ==> Money Spent
Sale_date
Sale_time
```

**Customer**

```
Cust_name
Cust_address
Cust_city
Cust_country
Cust_phone
Cust_age
Cust_sex
```

Comment: Don't you have `Customer_ID` field in the table `Customer`?

Comment: What does your query look like right now?

Comment: With this definition you have no way of relating a cust_country to any sale. otherwise is would be something like select country, avg(money_spent) from sale, customer where sale.customer_id = customer.id group by customer.country

Comment: Sorry.  The Sale table is: Sale_ID (Primary Key), Payment_ID (Foreign Key), Ship_ID (Foreign Key), Customer_ID (Foreign Key), Sale_total, Sale_date, Sale_time.  The Customer table is: Customer_ID (Primary Key), Cust_name, Cust_address, Cust_city, Cust_country, Cust_phone, Cust_age, Cust_sex.

Comment: Sale_total column contains the data of total amount spent during each sale.  I need to find the average amount of the sale_total column and group it by customer's country.  I apologise for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a link between the Sale and Customer tables. Presumably place Customer_ID in the Customer table as a primary key, and have Customer_ID in the Sale table be a foreign key. Assuming you do that, you can then run the below query.

```
SELECT
AVG(S.Sale_Total) Spent,
c.Cust_country
FROM
Sale S
INNER JOIN
Customer C on S.Customer_ID=C.Customer_ID
GROUP BY C.Cust_Country
```

This tells you the average amount spent, and the country where it was spent.

The key to understanding this answer is that `AVG` (the average function) is an aggregate function, as it combines things. Often when you have an aggregate function, you have to group the other columns, hence why we included the `GROUP BY` clause.

The reason you need Customer Id in the Customer table (apart from being the logical place for it) is so that you can establish a relationship between the Customer and Sale tables.

Another way to establish the relation is you can create a new table to link Customer and Sale together. Call it Customer Sales. For example:

**Customer_Sales**

```
Customer_Id
Sale_Id
```

Then you'd adjust the query to join based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
SELECT C.Cust_country as Country, AVG(S.Sale_total) as Spent
FROM Sale S INNER JOIN
Customer C on S.Customer_ID=C.Customer_ID
GROUP BY C.Cust_country
```

`AVG` is an aggregate function that evaluates the average of an expression over a set of rows.

Read more about [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj32693.html).

Comment: What are the ForeignKey and PrimaryKey columns? And wouldn't he want to know which country the sales were spent on, rather than just a list of totals?

Comment: @mason: There should be a FK and PK. Ask OP. I have provided the structure.

Comment: Maybe there should be, but it appears there is not. Perhaps you should wait until the OP has provided more details prior to answering.

Comment: @mason: providing idea to solve the problem doesn't mean that it is  a bad answer, my friend.

Comment: @Raging Bull: Yes I tried it. Much appreciated.  However, I need to display the information by each country.  Could you suggest something to help with this.  Thanks.

Comment: The reason I downvoted it was that you did not explain that Customer Id needs to be in the Customer table, and that your answer does not show the country where the money was spent. And simply providing a query without any explanation doesn't help people learn nearly as much as when you also provide an explanation.

Comment: @mason: I hope, anyone with a basic knowledge of SQL know what PK and FK are. BTW, Why do I need a down vote even now?

Comment: I downvoted before you added the customer country to the select clause. I've now removed the downvote. However, you still provided no explanation as to why the query is the way it is. He may know what a primary key and foreign key are, but you shouldn't assume that. And even knowing what they are, you still need to explain why it's necessary to have them in order to understand the solution.